# flutter web DataTable scrolling - horrid performance

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Scrolling in Flutter web appears to perform badly compared to running the same code on an emulator or actual device.  With DataTable the performance is unusable.

Is this a known issue?  Or is there something I can do to improve the situation?

Edit/update (2021)

This is much improved at present.  I'd say mostly fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue - see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/42987

I've had moderate success improving scroll performance when building with CanvasKit:

`flutter run -d chrome --profile --dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_USE_SKIA=true`

However, this may cause other issues with widget sizing/text rendering/etc. Unfortunately given Flutter Web is still in beta, these types of issues are to be expected.

According to the roadmap (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Roadmap), bug fixes for the web (and desktop) are a priority for 2020, so I am hopeful that some of these issues to be resolved later in the year.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to implement paging heavily.  The paging is done client-side since that makes most sense.